# Between/Timerange LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, datetime, date

My intention here is to select all entries (Bookings) between "begin" (begin_prefix) and "end" (end_prefix)

***BUT! The important thing is:***

If I have a booking at 07:25-10:00 - you query for 09:00-10:00 it should still show the booking because it reserves the room until 10 no matter what ..

So ..

07.25-10.00 booking means query for 09:00-10.00 still returns a list of bookings within 09:00-10.00 ***(which means 07.25-10.00 is included)***

```
        public static List<booking> Today(DateTime begin, DateTime end)
        {
        try
        {
            IFormatProvider Culturez = new CultureInfo(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["locale"].ToString(), true);
            DateTime begin_prefix = DateTime.ParseExact(begin.ToString(), "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss", Culturez);
            DateTime end_prefix = DateTime.ParseExact(end.ToString(), "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss", Culturez);

            dbDataContext db = new dbDataContext();

            // gives bookings BEFORE begin_prefix (why?)
            IQueryable<booking> bQ = from b in db.bookings
              where begin_prefix >= b.Starts &&
              b.Ends <= end_prefix &&
              b.Ends > b.Starts &&
              b.pointsbookings.Count > 0
              select b;
            // ^gives bookings BEFORE begin_prefix (why?)

            List<booking> bL = bQ.ToList();

            return bL;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
```

I've tried getting this right for some time now .. Seems everytime I correct it to something new, a new overlap or selection outside the two begin/end dates seem to appear :(

**UPDATE CRITERIA and SOURCE:** Bookings has to be WITHIN "begin_prefix" and "end_prefix" or on the exact same time ..

.. currently the above code gives me bookings BEFORE begin_prefix date, which is not intentioned! We're in 2011, I got bookings from 2010 as well! **

**NEW!! UPDATED:**

This is what I have:

SEARCH.START >= BOOKING.START

BOOKING.END <= SEARCH.END

... the problem comes up when ..

BOOKING entry: 10:00(Start)-14:00(End)

This means according to above:
08.59 >= 10.00
(SEARCH.START >= BOOKING.START)

It will never include it. But it should, since this is the same room and the seats are booked individually!

Comment: Tell us what your exact criteria are. Do `Starts` and `Ends` both need to be within `begin_prefix` and `end_prefix` or what?

Comment: Lots of people put effort into helping you out.  Deleting this question would result in them losing rep.  If your issue is solved by some other means, leave an answer with your solution and select it when the option becomes available.  Helps people who have similar issues and doesn't penalize those that tried to help.

Answer (score 1):

IMHO, it should be like this:

```
from b in db.bookings
where begin_prefix <= b.Starts && b.Starts < end_prefix && b.Ends <= end_prefix && bEnds >= b.Starts && b.pointsbookings.Count > 0
select b;
```

The important change is `begin_prefix <= b.Starts` instead of `begin_prefix >= b.Starts`. I also added a check that `bEnds >= b.Starts`, just to be sure.

BTW: The part you marked as **IMPORTANT** seems like complete nonsense to me.

Comment: updated source + some criteria info, currently gives me bookings before 2011, which is not intentional!

Comment: @dezza: Just implement the fix in my answer! Or think a little bit for yourself: You are asking your database to return bookings for which their start date is LESS THAN `begin_prefix`. So if `begin_prefix` is 01.01.2011 it will only return bookings from 2010 and earlier.

Comment: dt=10-03-2011&sTime=09:00&eTime=15:25 - date, start, end - this doesn't give me the entry I wanted which is "S: 10-03-2011 08:25:00, E: 10-03-2011 15:25" you see, even if the begin_prefix is larger than b.Starts it should still show!

Comment: I repeat: Change your code so that it implements my fix. Other than that, I don't really undersand your comment.

Comment: [BOOKING: 10-03-2011 08:25:00 to 10-03-2011 15:25:00] - Now, if input search is [10-03-2011 09:00:00 to 10-03-2011 15:25:00] .. b.Ends > b.Starts
b.Starts < b.Ends

end_prefix >= b.Ends
begin_prefix >= b.Starts

b.Ends > begin_prefix
b.Starts < end_prefix

begin_prefix < end_prefix
end_prefix > begin_prefix

Comment: I will not answer any more of your comments until you fixed your code! **Don't you read what I am writing you?**

Comment: begin_prefix is not less that b.Starts. Like I tried to explain in my update post above. 07:25-10.00 booking entry means 09:00-10.00 should match this entry.

Comment: So you want a booking to match, if it is only partly in your timespan?

Comment: @Daniel Hilgarth: It's not even worth your time. OP is struggling with _logic_ and keeps changing the requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't your begin_prefix <= b.starts and > end_prefix?

Comment: updated source + some criteria info, currently gives me bookings before 2011, which is not intentional!

Comment: If I have a booking at 07:25-10:00 - you query for 09:00-10:00 it should still show the booking because it reserves the room until 10 no matter what ..

Answer (score 0):

In this way you will select the correct bookings in the range:

```
IQueryable<booking> bQ = from b in db.bookings
                         where b.Starts >= begin_prefix && b.Ends <= end_prefix
                         where b.pointsbookings.Any()
                         select b;
```

Comment: updated source + some criteria info, currently gives me bookings before 2011, which is not intentional!

Answer (score 0):

Here:

```
IQueryable<booking> bQ = from b in db.bookings
                         where b.Starts >= begin_prefix &&
                               b.Ends <= end_prefix &&
                               b.Starts < b.Ends
                               b.pointsbookings.Count > 0
                         select b;
```

You want the start time to be after the begin prefix (`b.Starts >= begin_prefix`), the end time to be before the end prefix (`b.Ends <= end_prefix`), and the end to come after the start (`b.Starts > b.Ends`). That is what this code is now saying. You basically had the inequalities reversed.

Comment: updated source + some criteria info, currently gives me bookings before 2011, which is not intentional!

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure what these represent but I'm wondering why `begin_prefix >= b.Starts`; shouldn't it be the reverse?

Comment: updated source + some criteria info, currently gives me bookings before 2011, which is not intentional!

Comment: "// ^gives bookings BEFORE begin_prefix (why?) " - because that's your condition! `begin_prefix >= b.Starts`, i.e. `b.Starts <= begin_prefix`.  This is what I  (and others) have pointed out in our answers.

Answer (score 0):

I took this question to mean, *"From a list of datetime-ranges, how can I find all that overlap a given datetime-range?"*

If that is truly what you are asking, then the query you are looking for is

```
//b overlaps the datetime-range [begin_prefix, end_prefix]
begin_prefix <= b.Ends && end_prefix >= b.Starts
```